# Drupal: Duplicate search block?

Tags: php, drupal

I want to duplicate the default search box and put it between some blocks on my left sidebar: so it would show up on every page twice ( top where it already is and on the left mid-sidebar ).

Is there an easy way to clone it and then make sure the IDs arent duplicates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add block with php filter:

```
print drupal_get_form('search_block_form');
```

or print it in page.tpl.php, example from Zen theme:

```
<?php if ($search_box): ?>
  <div id="search-box">
  <?php print $search_box; ?>
  </div> <!-- /#search-box -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: How would I implement this though if I already have existing blocks generated by `echo $left;`? As previously stated I want it between blocks. As far as I know I can't embed server-side within blocks.

Comment: Well, it doesnt seem to be generating it because it probably isnt defined at that point in time.

Comment: Did you enable Search module?

Comment: I did. This won't generate it, you have to create a custom module.

Answer (score 3):

For Drupal 7, use:

```
<?php print render(drupal_get_form('search_block_form')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use another module for this and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

**This method is not very secure, but very fast**

- Switch on "PHP filter" on "All modules" page
- Create block in admin-panel.
- Insert in body module.

  $form_search = drupal_get_form('search_block_form');
   print render($form_search);

**More correct method:**

1) initialize a variable in template.php

```
<?php
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  $search_form = drupal_get_form('search_form');
  $search_form_box = drupal_render($search_form);
  $vars['search_box'] = $search_form_box;
} ?>
```

2) Editing page.tpl in your theme. Adding:

```
<?php if ($search_box): ?>
  <div id="search-box">
  <?php print $search_box; ?>
  </div> <!-- /#search-box -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

edit the module modules/search/search.module the funcion search_block. 
just add as much search blocks you want.:
instead:

```
function search_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0) {
  if ($op == 'list') {
    $blocks[0]['info'] = t('Search form');
    // Not worth caching.
    $blocks[0]['cache'] = BLOCK_NO_CACHE;
    return $blocks;
  }
  else if ($op == 'view' && user_access('search content')) {
    $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('search_block_form');
    $block['subject'] = t('Search');
    return $block;
  }
}
```

i think this would work:

```
function search_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0) {
  if ($op == 'list') {
    $blocks[0]['info'] = t('Search form');
    // Not worth caching.
    $blocks[0]['cache'] = BLOCK_NO_CACHE;
    $blocks[1]['info'] = t('Search form');
    $blocks[1]['cache'] = BLOCK_NO_CACHE;
    return $blocks;
  }
  else if ($op == 'view' && user_access('search content')) {
    $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('search_block_form');
    $block['subject'] = t('Search');
    return $block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Never edit modules, use hooks, theming etc... If no way to fix, upload to drupal.org patches - it is recommended, but not in current question.